# Rename output columns of groupby and count in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

Could you tell me how to count the number of citations per patent for the following data?

```
"CITING","CITED"
3858241,956203
3858241,1324234
3858241,3398406
3858241,3557384
3858241,3634889
3858242,1515701
3858242,3319261
3858242,3668705
3858242,3707004
3858243,2949611
3858243,3146465
3858243,3156927
```

The "CITED" column holds the Patent number.

The desired output is a DataFrame in the following format:

```
 +--------+------+
 |NPatent|ncitations|
 +--------+------+
 | 3060453|  3   |
 | 3390168|  6   |
 | 3626542| 18   |
 | 3611507|  5   |
 | 3000113|  4   |
```

I'm currently using the following code, which is not generating the desired output:

```
# Importing Pandas 
import pandas as pd

# Reading the file in zipped format and save it to a DataFrame
df = pd.read_csv('/datos/cite75_99.txt.bz2', compression='bz2', header=0, sep=',', quotechar='"')

df = df.groupby('CITED').CITING.nunique()

print(df)
```

I would appreciate your help in getting the desired DataFrame.

Thank you!

Comment: this is a pandas code, you want solution in pyspark or pandas?

Comment: pandas, please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
df = df.groupby('CITED')['CITING'].count().reset_index()
df.columns = ['NPatent','ncitations']
df
```

Comment: you might want to reset the index first: `df.groupby('CITED')['CITING'].count().reset_index()`

Comment: This worked. Resetting the index was necessary for it to work. Thank you.